curl command not working inside the docker
We have an API endpoint that is accessible from our company's IP address. The curl command works fine when executed from Windows PowerShell and also functions correctly inside WSL2. However, when running the same curl command from a Docker container within WSL2, it fails with an SSL error.
Here is the error message:
curl -v https://wrdes.dev.lktr.com/sdsdss/ewf/report?reportName=XYZ
*   Trying 10.44.11.112:443...
* Connected to wrdes.dev.lktr.com (10.44.11.112) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to wrdes.dev.lktr.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to wrdes.dev.lktr.com:443

I have attempted to resolve the issue by updating the certificates and modifying resolv.conf, but the problem persists.
Please note that the Docker image I am using is from Astro Airflow, which limits my ability to modify the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile simply references the Astro API where the Dockerfile resides.
Do you have any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Apparently it's resolving DNS as 10.44.11.112, so it's probably a certificate issue. Do you have openssl in this container? Then, run: openssl s_client -showcerts -servername wrdes.dev.kltr.com -connect wrdes.dev.lktr.com:443 < /dev/null and verify that all chain is resolved.

What do you mean with "attempted to resolve the issue by updating the certificates". Please enhance this point.

Run nslookup wrdes.dev.lktr.com inside docker container and post result.

@ClaudioWeiler when i run the command I get the output connected and then it is stuck forever.  openssl s_client -showcerts -servername wrdes.dev.kltr.com -connect wrdes.dev.lktr.com:443 < /dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)

CONNECTED(00000003)  is the output of a successfull hit. I see that there are a typo on my sample, but it should not be the hanging cause. Now it appears to be a network issue. You can try the openssl command on WSL, just to be shure.
